# Calendar integration and sync-ing (Swift)

Tags: ios, calendar

I have an app with a calendar integration that I am working on, but once it adds to the calendar then any changes only create a new calendar entry.  How can I get these to stay connected so any changes in the app are updated to the calendar?

Comment: i think this question can be a bit more specific?
What calendar? EKCalendar? or some custom one?

Comment: @JTAppleCalendarforiOSSwift, I am using a custom  EKEventStore.  Would it be better to use EKCalendar?  I'd also like to have the option to select which calendar would be used for users with multiple calendars.